# If $2a_{n+2} \le a_{n+1}+a_n$, then $\lim \sup a_n \le \frac23 a_2 + \frac13 a_1$

Tags: recurrence-relations

This is a reformulation of
a deleted question:

If 
$a_1 > 0$
and
$a_2 > 0$
and
$2a_{n+2} \le a_{n+1}+a_n$, 
show that
 $\lim \sup a_n \le \frac23 a_2 + \frac13 a_1$.

My proof involves showing that
$a_{n+2}
\le u_{n} a_{n+1} + (1-u_n)a_n
$
where
$u_n \to \frac23$,
and I wondered if
there is a simpler proof.

I will post my proof
in a couple of days
if no one does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems entirely straightforward.

If $b_1=a_1$, $b_2=a_2$ and $b_{n+2}=(b_n+b_{n+1})/2$ then $a_n\le b_n$.
Now $b_n=\alpha+\beta(-1/2)^n$, so $b_n\to\alpha=\frac23b_2+\frac13b_1$.

Comment: Very nice, and a lot simpler than mine.

Comment: I proposed a solution to the same problem [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208747/need-help-finding-the-limit-of-this-sequence/2208857#2208857). Is your solution essentially the same, just skipping some details, or am I missing obvious reasoning why $b_n$ and $\alpha$ are the way they are?